# java api to get conference roomlist using EWS

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am trying to fetch roomlist using EWS services, but getting empty response, we are using 2010 server.please let me know any solutions to address this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very hard to answer questions like these without any accompanying code

Answer (score 0):

By default there are no room lists configured in Exchange. Your Exchange Admin has to configure them. From [How to: Get room lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn643730(v=exchg.150).aspx):

> Room lists don't exist by default; your administrator needs to create and organize them.

A room list is a special kind of distribution list. Information on creating them can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633471(v=exchg.141).aspx).